# Memory Leak When SSL and Client Certificates Are Used With the HttpWebRequest Object

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, memory-leaks, httpwebrequest

I am using `HttpWebRequest` object to upload files using `SSL` with client certificate, I have a valid certificate on my server, My application is having a memory leak issue and Microsoft has posted something related to the issue on the following link:

[FIX: Memory Leak When SSL and Client Certificates Are Used With the HttpWebRequest Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831578)

Is there any work around to avoid this memory leak specially that each request is consuming 8K leaked memory, this will cause my application to consume so much memory.

---

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
```

---

memory leaks were detected using [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) and it shows the `HttpWebRequest` object has array of bytes that leaks the memory, I am deposing both stream and request objects.

I have tried this case with `SSL` and `without SSL` the leaks have disappeared in non `SSL` Requests.

Comment: We can't help you dial a phone number.

Comment: if you have noticed **Article ID: 831578 - Last Review: October 25, 2005 - Revision: 1.5** it's been 6 years I thought maybe someone have faced the same issue.

Comment: That leak only applies to .NET 1.1. Why do you believe you are encountering it? (assuming you're not running 1.1)

Comment: @blowdart: because when I stop using SSL the memory leak no longer exist.

Comment: But you haven't said how you detect a leak, after all it's hard to figure out leaks in managed code, it could simply be the GC not sweeping yet. Or further down the line you're doing stream manipulation and not disposing the stream. This needs way more information before anyone can offer help - how you detect the leak, what the numbers are, windbg stack dumps, the rest of the code around those four lines etc etc. The fact that the KB article has not been updated indicates that the fix was rolled into 2.0 and beyond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply set the `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property of your `HttpWebRequest` object to false:

```
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Note : The Framework caches SSL sessions as they are created and attempts to reuse a cached session for a new request, if possible. When attempting to reuse an SSL session, the Framework uses the first element of ClientCertificates (if there is one), or tries to reuse an anonymous sessions if ClientCertificates is empty.

Other Note : For performance reasons, you shouldn't add a client certificate to a HttpWebRequest unless you know the server will ask for it.
For a code example illustrating how to enumerate the certificates in the client certificate store, see the X509Certificate2Collection class.

Or try to use this :

```
request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

Comment: @Yahya - is there a way to determine whether the server is asking for a client certificate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WinDbg, a debugger which is part of the Windows SDK to better explore how memory is being managed for you. Whilst not as friendly as the 3rd party options out there it allows you to go lower and figure out if what you are seeing is indeed a leak. There's no real easy way to tell where your problem lies, you create new instances of ValidateRemoteCertificate, which I presume is your code, and could itself not be freeing all it uses, which in turn can cause the GC not to clean up the request.

To get started you can read

- [Get Started: Debugging Memory Related Issues in .Net Application Using WinDBG and SOS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/WinDBGAndSOS.aspx)
- [Where's your leak at?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx)
- [Tracking down managed memory leaks (how to find a GC leak)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx)

If, after that, you truly believe this is a .NET framework bug, and not in your own code then report it. There are a couple of ways to do this, via [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/), or if this is impacting you heavily you can place a [support incident](http://support.microsoft.com/select/default.aspx?target=assistance&c1=501&) with Microsoft. If you go the support incident route you will need a credit card. If your problem is due to a bug in the .NET framework you will not be charged.